# MVC - PartialView doesn't find events in View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, events, model-view-controller, telerik

I have a window and its content is being loaded via a partial view. As putting jscript-code into the partial view only causes problems I tried to put it into the view which contains the window.

Debugging this page I get an undefined-error right away while loading the view on an DropDownList-event and none of the other events work either. I spent the last few hours looking for a solution, but couldn't find anything.

View:

```
@model List<CrmProfileVM>

@using DAKCrmImport.Models;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Profilübersicht</h2>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CrmProfileVM>().Name("gvCrmProfile").BindTo(Model).Columns(c =>
        {
            c.Template(t => { }).HeaderTemplate("").ClientTemplate(@"
                <a href='javascript: void(0)' class='abutton delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)' title='Löschen'>button delete</a>
                <a href='javascript: void(0)' class='abutton edit' onclick='editRow(this)' title='Bearbeiten'>button edit</a>")
            .Width(250);
            c.Bound(i => i.Name);
            c.Bound(i => i.JobCount).Title("Jobanzahl");
            c.Bound(i => i.CrmType).Title("Typ");
            c.Bound(i => i.CreatedBy).Title("Ersteller");
            c.Bound(i => i.UserGroup).Title("Benutzergruppe");
            c.Bound(i => i.CreatedAt).Title("Erstellt am").Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}");
            c.Bound(i => i.LastUpdatedBy).Title("Letzte Anpassung durch");
            c.Bound(i => i.LastUpdatedAt).Title("Letzte Anpassung am").Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}");
        }) //"<a href='" + @Url.Action("Add", "Profile") + "' class='abutton create' title='Neues Profil anlegen'>button create</a>"
        .ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Template("<a href='javascript: void(0)' class='abutton create' title='Neues Profil anlegen' onclick='createProfile()'>button create</a>"))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 680px;" })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
        .Scrollable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("tpCrmProfile")
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(5))
        .Filterable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
            .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "Grid"))
            .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Destroy", "Grid"))
            .Create("Add", "Profile")
        )
)


@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("createProfileWindow")
    .Title("Profilerstellung")
    .Content(@<text>
    </text>)
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
    .Width(700)
    .Height(800)
    .Visible(false)
    .Iframe(true)
    .LoadContentFrom("Add", "Profile")
    .Scrollable(false)
    .AutoFocus(true)
)
<script>

    function createProfile() {
        var window = $("#createProfileWindow").data("kendoWindow");
        window.open();
        window.center();
    }


    function showDetails() {

    }


    function onSourceDataTypeSelect(e) {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
        var ddlSeparator = $("#Separator").data("kendoDropDownList");

        if (dataItem.Text == "csv") {
            ddlSeparator.enable();
        } else {
            ddlSeparator.select(0);
            ddlSeparator.enable(false);
        }
    }
</script>
```

PartialView:

```
@model DAKCrmImportModel.Model.Entities.Base.CrmProfile

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_CrmProfileAdd";
}

@(Html.Kendo().Notification().Name("gridNotification"))

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "addProfileForm", novalidate = "false" }))
{   
        <ul id="progressbar">
                <li class="active">Grundeinstellungen</li>
                <li>CRM-Einstellungen</li>
                <li>Mapping anlegen</li>
        </ul>
        <fieldset id="fs1">
            <h2 class="fs-title">Grundinformationen</h2>
            <div class="formClearContainer">
                @(Html.ActionLink("Formular leeren", MVC.Profile.ClearForm(), new { @class = "clearForm" }))
            </div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "label req" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "input" })
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "label" })
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "input", rows = "3", cols = "25" })
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserGroupId, new { @class = "label req" })
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.UserGroupId)
                .OptionLabel("Bitte auswählen... ")
                .BindTo(Model.UserGroupList)
            .Popup(p => p.AppendTo("#fs1"))
            )
            @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.SourceDataType, new { @class ="label req" }))
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => Model)
                .BindTo(EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(DAKCrmImportModel.Model.Entities.Base.SourceDataType)))
                .OptionLabel("Bitte auswählen... ")
                .Name("SourceDataType")
                .Events( e=>
                    {
                        e.Select("onSourceDataTypeSelect");
                    }))
            @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Separator, new { @class="label req" }))
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => Model)
            .BindTo(EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(DAKCrmImportModel.Model.Entities.Base.SeparatorType)))
                .OptionLabel("Bitte auswählen... ")
                .Name("Separator")
                .Events( e=>
                    e.Select("onSeparatorTypeSelect"))
                .Enable(false))
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Weiter" style="display:block"/>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="fs2">
            <h2 class="fs-title">CRM-Einstellungen</h2>
            <div class="formClearContainer">
                @(Html.ActionLink("Formular leeren", MVC.Profile.ClearForm(), new { @class = "clearForm" }))
            </div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrdnungsbegriffTypeId, new { @class = "label req" })
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.OrdnungsbegriffTypeId)
                .OptionLabel("Bitte auswählen...")
                .BindTo(Model.OrdnungsbegriffTypeList)
            .Popup(p => p.AppendTo("#fs2"))
            )
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CrmTypeId, new { @class = "label req" })
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => Model.CrmTypeId)
                .Name("CrmTypeId")
                .OptionLabel("Bitte auswählen...")
                .BindTo(Model.CrmTypeList)
            .Popup(p => p.AppendTo("#fs2"))
                .Events(e =>
                    e.Select("onCrmTypeSelect"))
            )
            <br />
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Zurueck" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Weiter" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Mapping anlegen</h2>
            <div class="formClearContainer">
                @(Html.ActionLink("Formular leeren", MVC.Profile.ClearForm(), new { @class = "clearForm" }))
            </div>
            @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                .Name("upMappingFile")
                .Multiple(false)
                .ShowFileList(true)
                .TemplateId("fuCsvTemplate")
                .Async(a => a
                    .AutoUpload(true)
                    .Save("SaveFile", "Mapping")
                    .Remove("RemoveFile", "Mapping")
                )
                .Enable(false)
                .Events(e => e
                    .Success("onSuccess")
                    .Upload("onUpload"))
                .Messages(m => m
                    .Select("Durchsuchen...")
                    .HeaderStatusUploading("Uploading...")
                    .HeaderStatusUploaded("Fertig"))
            )
            <div id="gridContainer">
            </div>
            @*<div id="appendTo" class="k-block"></div>*@
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Zurueck" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Speichern"/>
</fieldset>
}
```

Controller-ActionResult:

```
public virtual ActionResult Add()
        {
            CrmProfile crmProfile = new CrmProfile();
            crmProfile = GetCrmProfile(crmProfile);

            return PartialView("_CrmProfileAdd", crmProfile);
        }
```

This isn't the complete code, but putting all of that in here would've been somewhat of an overkill.

So .. simple question: Why the hell doesnt the partial view find events in the view that is containing it? How can I solve this elegantly?

Thanks in advance, guys. :)

[UPDATE 1]
So after taking the scriptreferences out of the partial view, which is a thing I have to do anyways. I get a "jQuery is not defined"-error when the page tries to initiate one of the Kendo/Telerik-controlls .. yaaaayy.

```
jQuery(function(){jQuery("#UserGroupId").kendoDropDownList({"dataSource":[{"Text":"0023 10 - VZ_RSA","Value":"1"}],"dataTextField":"Text","popup":{"appendTo":"#fs1"},"dataValueField":"Value","optionLabel":"Bitte auswählen... "});});
```

I started researching again and tried to put in a @section scripts into the view and inserted all scripts. Unfortunately it didn't do a thing and yes, I do have the RenderSection-part in my _Layout. I really don't know what's going on. Fiddler doesn't show any errors either btw.

Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/<kendo ui version>/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/<kendo ui version>/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />*@
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Meine ASP.NET-Anwendung</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryeasing")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div id="logo"></div>
            <div id="logoHead">CrmImport</div>
            <div id="links">
                <a href="#">Über uns</a>
                <a href="#">Hilfe</a>
                <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="breadCrumpContainer">
            <div id="breadCrump">@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]</div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                @* Linkname, Action, Controller *@
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", MVC.Home.Index()) </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Meine Profile", MVC.Profile.Index())
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Meine Jobs", MVC.Profile.Index())
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Administration</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Usergruppen verwalten", "Index", "UserGroups")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log", "Index", "Log")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Globale Profile", "Index", "GlobalProfiles")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("News verwalten", "Index", "News")</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <content>
                    <div id="userBox">
                        @Html.Action("_User", "User")
                    </div>
                </content>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="push"></div>
    <footer>Copyright © DAK-Gesundheit 2015</footer>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
<link href="~/Styles/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Honestly, if you aren't reloading that partial a lot, just put the javascript in the partial.

Comment: The partialview is basically a form and for as long as I have the scripts inside of the partial view the submit happens twice and thats Happening, because I have to reference jquery both in the layout and in the partial view for it to work... I'm really starting to hate MVC.

Comment: In the parent view, place the code in a section scripts tag, but not your code in the partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the Problem was the Kendo.Window or rather the time ist content is loaded which is at the moment the parent view is build.

To solve the problem I had to load the windows Content when I click on specific buttons for editing and creating.

You can ignore the whole href-part. It's for debugging.

```
function createProfile() {
        var window = $("#createProfileWindow").data("kendoWindow");

        //Dynamisches Vorgehen nicht möglich. Daher muss die URL untersucht werden
        //Hinweis: Für Produktiv/Test ist diese Funktion wahrscheinlich nicht notwendig, da Index nie "direkt" aufgerufen wird
        var url = 'Profile/Add';
        if ($(location).attr('href').indexOf("Index") >= 0) {
            url = '@MVC.Profile.ActionNames.Add';
        }

        $("#createProfileWindow").kendoWindow({
            content: {
                url: url
            }
        });
        window.open();
        window.center();

        profileId = null;
    }
```